# How to enable the ability of using gift cards at check out

Tags: magento-enterprise, checkout, gift-card

I've been searching on how to add the ability for customers to use gift cards on the check out page on my Magento site and so far no luck. I am running on Magento Enterprise so the function is available for use but where I'm stuck at is where I can enable the function to redeem gift cards. Right now the check out page at the payment gateway only provides the  options of payment either Paypal or credit card options. Could I enable this feature through the Admin Configuration and if so, could you please provide me the path on how?? Or would I need to do something more in-depth than that?

I appreciate the help!

Comment: I never tried it, but assume you get a coupon code which you can use?

Comment: Coupon codes and gift card codes are two different animals. I did try, just to see what would happen if I used the gift card code (which was created in the backend), and see if it works but it doesn't. I need that static block that asks or even to check the balance of a gift card purchased through the site. I hope this makes better sense. Thanks though for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is **"Enterprise_GiftCard"** set to **"Enable"** in *System > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced*? If so, are you using a custom theme for your checkout page which does not include the gift card code box? Additionally, I assume all your gift cards are set to "redeemable" and list the correct website to be redeemed at?

#### Edit:

It occurs to me that you are asking about the path of the template file. It would depend on if you are using onepage checkout or not, but it should be in `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/` and if you are using onepage, the directory will be `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/`

Comment: I did check the configuration settings, just to be sure because sometimes those simple little settings can be forgotten. It is enabled in the advance settings and I also have it set "redeemable" as well. Looks it comes down to finding that gift card code box and including in my custom theme, which I've uploaded the correct files to do so and it's still not showing up! But the your input has been helpful because I know where to start looking on the backend. Thank you!

Comment: @Ang and ddavidn, Did you ever find the exact answer to this? I'm looking for the HTML in the template files and not finding where you input the gift card code to apply it to an order. What is the specific template file (for either onepage or regular)?

Comment: @NickRolando Try line 40 of `app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/giftcardaccount/cart/block.phtml`?